# Manipulate an excel file to produce a new file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and am stuck with a problem that I don't know how to approach. Please help to guide me in the right direction.

I have a data frame like below:

```
   SN  5 10   15   20   25   30   40   50
0  A1  P  P  FM1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  A2  P  P    P  FM3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  A3  P  P    P    P    P    P    P  FM2
3  A4  P  P    P    P    P  FM1  NaN  NaN
4  A5  P  P    P    P    P    P    P    P
5  A6  P  P    P    P    P    P    P    P
6  A7  P  P  FM2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  A8  P  P    P    P  FM2  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  A9  P  P    P    P    P  FM1  NaN  NaN
```

- `5,15,20` etc. are checkpoints and are currently stored as column index(type: object).
- `SN` is serial numbers.
- `P` = `pass` and `FM1`/`FM2` etc are fail modes.

Now what I am trying to get to is the information below.

1. For each SN, how do I find and store the column name with the last 'P'
2. For each SN, how do I find and store the FM type(FM1/Fm2/FM3 etc.) that occurs after the last 'P' along with the column name.

ex. For SN- A1, the table will look like

```
SN  FM  P. F. 
A1. FM1 10 15
```

3. For rows with 'P' in all columns the table will look like

```
SN. FM  P. F 
A5. FM1 50
A5. FM2 50
A5  FM3 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first create a function that loops (backwards) through the columns, when provided with a row, until it finds the value of 'P':

```
def F(row_dict,column_list):
    ## Loop through column_list backwards
    reversed_column_list = reversed(column_list)
    for i in range(len(column_list)):
        column_name = reversed_column_list[i]
        ## If we're on the last column and the value is P
        if (i == 0) & (row_dict[column_name] == "P"):
            return (
                ## SN value
                row_dict['SN'],
                ## FM value
                "FM1",
                ## P value
                reversed_column_list[0],
                ## F value
                None
            )
        ## If we're on any other column and the value is P
        if row_dict[column_name] == "P":
            return (
                ## SN value
                row_dict['SN'],
                ## FM value
                row_dict[reversed_column_list[i-1]],
                ## P value
                column_name,
                ## F value
                reversed_column_list[i-1]
            )
```

Then loop through every row in your table (I've assumed it's called `df`) and call the function on the row:

```
sn_list = []
fm_list = []
p_list = []
f_list = []
column_list = [5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50]
for row_dict in df.values:
    sn,fm,p,f = F(row_dict,column_list)
    if f is None:
        ## If the last value returned is None, add one row for each of the FM types
        for FM in ['FM1','FM2','FM3']:
            sn_list.append(sn)
            fm_list.append(FM)
            p_list.append(p)
            f_list.append(f)
    else:
        sn_list.append(sn)
        fm_list.append(FM)
        p_list.append(p)
        f_list.append(f)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'SN' : sn_list,
        'FM' : fm_list,
        'P' : p_list,
        'F' : f_list
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting the following error when I run this code: name 'reverse' is not defined. Is it a pandas/numpy function? Also, can the first_valid_index or last_valid_index function be somehow used?

Comment: @AnuragGupta apologies, that should be `reversed` instead, I'll edit my answer. Yes, I believe you could use those two methods too

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.